# How to change jdk version in tomcat which is on the docker

Tags: java, docker, jsp, tomcat

I want to use jdk-17 in tomcat container on docker
cuz openjdk-11.0.14.1+1 which is now on the tomcat doesn't support my code
(Error : The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved.)
which make me sad

The code is working on eclipse with tomcat 10 and jdk17.0.2

so I tried to download jdk17 on tomcat
and change the path on /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:
Tomcat started.
```

but the java --version

```
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

is still same

could you help me to let me know how to fix it..

Comment: It looks like tomcat is correctly using java 17. Seems like what is wrong is your path variable, so running java on your command line does not use the newly installed java 17. Also: you should build a new docker image with java 17, as installing it in the container will be reverted when it's being recreated.

Comment: `javax.servlet.http.ServletRequest` is not part of the JDK - not of the JDK 11 and also not of the JDK 17. Tomcat however should include it. Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: thank you for answer but the code still doesn't work..

Comment: I think it is tomcat 10 latest version

Comment: You have tomcat images with jdk17 - https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat?tab=tags&page=1&name=jdk17

Comment: can you share here the Dockerfile ?

Comment: _"The code is working on eclipse with tomcat 10 and jdk17.0.2"_: I somehow doubt that, since Tomcat 10 uses `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` instead of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`.